# Download all packages from private nuget feed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I want to download all packages in all version from my private nuget feed.
Thats it. I have no problem in using powershell, bash, package manager what ever.

I can't use a placeholder project - that references all packages and copy my cache, because I need all versions.

Any idea?

I am working with a private nuget-feed. The feed is kind of broken, but its not in my hand to fix it. So I have to go this way...

Comment: How was this private feed implemented? If it's a file share you could simply copy the folder contents. Even NuGet feeds implemented as services typically store packages in a folder.

Comment: I only have an IP and credentials. How can I access the folder? Actually no idea whats behind - thats kind of the problem. I thought there would maybe be a cool command or some possibilities for a powershell script.

Comment: There are some link/tools but some of them looks old. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nuget.Downloader  https://gist.github.com/bevand/e5325035a31c281f4532e330005216cc#file-ps-download-all-nuget-packages

Comment: Thanks will check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PowerShell you can do this:

```
>Find-Package -Name='Package_Name'  -AllVersions -Source Local | Install-Package -Destination 'C:\SOME_PATH'
```

The command will find all the versions of packages with name like 'Package_Name' in the source Local (has to be specified in NuGet.config), and install them to 'C:\SOME_PATH' folder. To get all the packages from the source remove the `-Name` parameter.

Then you can get each .nupkg file from its own folder.

Comment: "Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]: "

Answer (score 10):

I created a better PowerShell here that download all packages for all versions

```
Find-Package -AllVersions -Source NuGet-Source | ForEach-Object {
   Install-Package -Name $_.Name -MaximumVersion $_.Version -Destination 'C:\Temp\Nuget\' -Source NuGet-Source -SkipDependencies
}
```

Comment: How can you install all versions?
" Unable to install, multiple packages matched . Please specify an exact -Name and -RequiredVersion."

Comment: It is already iterates over all versions in Find-Package, so result should be all versions of packages installed

Answer (score 4):

These solutions did not work for me, so the following is what I did. I was working to migrate TFS 2017 feed to Azure DevOps hosted feed.

First, I downloaded all packages from the on-premise self hosted feed using this script in Powershell ISE:

```
# --- settings ---
# use nuget v2 feed for this script
# v2 feed is sometimes same url as v3, just change /v3/index.json to /v2/ 
$feedUrlBase = "http://servername:8080/tfs/MOMCollection/_packaging/bbd0bd78-205f-48af-ac25-6eef6470adb4/nuget/v2/"  # be sure to include trailing slash 
# the rest will be params when converting to funclet
$latest = $false
$overwrite = $true
$top = $null #use $top = $null to grab all , otherwise use number
$destinationDirectory = join-path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) "NuGetLocal"

# --- locals ---
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

# following is required if authenticating to TFS using integrated credentials
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials=$true


# --- functions ---

# download entries on a page, recursively called for page continuations
function DownloadEntries {
 param ([string]$feedUrl) 
 $feed = [xml]$webClient.DownloadString($feedUrl)
 $entries = $feed.feed.entry 
 $progress = 0
            
 foreach ($entry in $entries) {
    $url = $entry.content.src
    $fileName = $entry.properties.id + "." + $entry.properties.version + ".nupkg"
    $saveFileName = join-path $destinationDirectory $fileName
    $pagepercent = ((++$progress)/$entries.Length*100)
    if ((-not $overwrite) -and (Test-Path -path $saveFileName)) 
    {
        write-progress -activity "$fileName already downloaded" `
                       -status "$pagepercent% of current page complete" `
                       -percentcomplete $pagepercent
        continue
    }
    write-progress -activity "Downloading $fileName" `
                   -status "$pagepercent% of current page complete" `
                   -percentcomplete $pagepercent

    [int]$trials = 0
    do {
        try {
            $trials +=1
            $webClient.DownloadFile($url, $saveFileName)
            break
        } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
            write-host "Problem downloading $url `tTrial $trials `
                       `n`tException: " $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    while ($trials -lt 3)
  }

  $link = $feed.feed.link | where { $_.rel.startsWith("next") } | select href
  if ($link -ne $null) {
    # if using a paged url with a $skiptoken like 
    # http:// ... /Packages?$skiptoken='EnyimMemcached-log4net','2.7'
    # remember that you need to escape the $ in powershell with `
    return $link.href
  }
  return $null
}  

# the NuGet feed uses a fwlink which redirects
# using this to follow the redirect
function GetPackageUrl {
 param ([string]$feedUrlBase) 
 $resp = [xml]$webClient.DownloadString($feedUrlBase)
 return $resp.service.GetAttribute("xml:base")
}

# --- do the actual work ---

# if dest dir doesn't exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationDirectory)) { 
    New-Item $destinationDirectory -type directory 
}

# set up feed URL
$serviceBase = $feedUrlBase
$feedUrl = $serviceBase + "Packages"
if($latest) {
    $feedUrl = $feedUrl + "?`$filter=IsLatestVersion eq true"
    if($top -ne $null) {
        $feedUrl = $feedUrl + "&`$orderby=DownloadCount desc&`$top=$top"
    }
}

while($feedUrl -ne $null) {
    $feedUrl = DownloadEntries $feedUrl
}
```

Next, I verified every version of every package was downloaded in .nupkg format, and they were. Next I uploaded to the new feed using powershell:

```
$destinationDirectory = join-path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) "NuGetLocal"

Get-ChildItem $destinationDirectory -Recurse -Filter *.nupkg | 
Foreach-Object {
    nuget push -Source "YOUR NUGEFEED NAME HERE" -ApiKey az $_.FullName
}
```

I hope this helps someone who is working to migrate nuget feeds.

Comment: Fwiw, I didn't have to put `vN` at the end, just ended with `nuget` as the url was listed in my Nuget Package Manager, and it seemed to work. Also worth noting that it saves to `join-path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) "NuGetLocal"`, not a local path, which is obvious after you c&p the code and notice nothing's happening, then read the code a little <strike>more closely</strike>. (Also don't c&p powershell without reading the code first.) But wow, awesome; thanks!

Comment: Could be that by default your nuget path was already v2- but I tried with v3 and was encountering failures in the script in many places so indicated it in comments that if there is some issue, make sure you indicate v2. Happy to help, I borrowed pieces of different scripts from different places, anymore chatgpt could probably just write it, but it's a great option to migrate feeds as there aren't many tools to historically grab every single package and move them to a new feed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to download, then save-package is more appropriate than install-package

This script saves all nuget packages from a nuget server (NuGet-Source) into the current directory

```
Find-Package -AllVersions -Source NuGet-Source | ForEach-Object {
  Save-Package -Name $_.Name -RequiredVersion $_.Version -Source NuGet-Source -Path '.'
}
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? I keep getting "query url .index.json is invalid"

Comment: Long time since I looked at this, and not touched it since. 

Check that the first bit of the pipe is working.  

'Find-Package -AllVersions -Source NuGet-Source`

I suspect that your 'NugGet-Source' is incorrect

Comment: I had to use the v2 api for some reason.