# How to Bulk Download Azure Artifacts Packages?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

My organization is moving our software packages (NuGet, NPM) to Azure Artifacts. We have approximately 50,000 NuGet packages (2GB) that we've pushed to Azure Artifacts.

Is there a way to to bulk-pull my packages from Azure Artifacts either to my machine or to Azure blob storage in case we are not satisfied with the product? I'm mainly concerned about pulling our NuGet packages because we have thousands of packages published.

I'm aware of [Download all packages from private nuget feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357378/download-all-packages-from-private-nuget-feed) but I'd like to know if there's a way to retrieve a zip file of all of our packages, or some other method to download all of our packages in bulk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't have a bulk download option, but it would be pretty easy to script something yourself.

First, you'll want to [get a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops). Make sure the PAT has the Packaging (read) scope. You will use the PAT as a password for authentication. The username you use doesn't matter.

Then, you'll need to get the list of all packages in the feed. You can use our [Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20packages?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API for that.

Then, for NuGet packages, the protocol is as follows:

1. Download the feed URL (from the Connect to Feed dialog, will end with `.../v3/index.json`)
2. Read the returned JSON document, get the @id attribute from the object with @type = `PackageBaseAddress/3.0.0`. This is the PackageBaseAddress. Note that the actual value is considered an implementation detail. Always retrieve the address from index.json.
3. If you do not already have the list of versions, download `{PackageBaseAddress}/{PackageName (lowercased)}/index.json` which will have the list as a JSON array (I suggest getting the versions this way since they will already be normalized)
4. Download the packages from `{PackageBaseAddress}/{PackageName (lowercase)}/{PackageVersion (normalized)}/{PackageName (lowercase)}.{PackageVersion (normalized)}.nupkg`

   - e.g. `{PackageBaseAddress}/restsharp/106.4.1/restsharp.106.4.1.nupkg`
   - Be sure to follow redirects, as the service will actually send you to download from our backend storage

For npm packages:

1. Get the Feed URL from the Connect to Feed dialog (it will end with `.../npm/registry`)
2. Download `{Feed URL}/{PackageName}` (for scoped packages include the scope, e.g. `{Feed URL}/@{Scope}/{PackageName}`)
3. Download URLs for each version are listed in the JSON response as versions.*.dist.tarball
4. Again, be sure to handle redirects when downloading the packages.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I have a question related to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download%20package?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Although the API call is slightly different from the download step you describe, the documentation above says "This API is intended for manual UI download options, not for programmatic access and scripting. You may be heavily throttled if accessing this api for scripting purposes." 

Is it fine to proceed with your steps?

Comment: I recommend using the method I described, which is the actual NuGet/npm download protocol used by the official clients, and is built to handle load.

Comment: In the method described here, Is there a way to get specific TFMs or list which TFMs are in each package or can that only be done via downloading the actual package and looking at the lib folder?

Comment: You would have to download the package. We don't presently examine packages to determine compatible TFMs in the service.

Comment: @JonathanMyers Being a bit late to the party, but what is meant by "Be sure to follow redirects..."? I scripted the 4 steps listed for NuGet packages and I am able to simply download the nupkg file that you can from step 4's assembled URI.

Comment: Your HTTP client must be set up to follow redirects then. We use Azure Blob Storage to store the actual contents of packages*. Rather than downloading the contents to our server and then send them on to you, we use a redirect to send your client to download directly from Azure Storage. (* this is an implementation detail subject to change at any time without notice)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and easiest way to bulk download azure artifacts are using ui or website.
Login and go to azure artifacts, select you want to download or select all. Initially when you click download you will see that only one the first one downloaded. The reason is browser automatically blocked popups. So you will see popup closed option on url bar , just allow popup. Now once you click download it will start downloading all.
Suggestion: change download location to a different path.